# Can't update because of "untrusted" packages?

Tags: upgrade, updates

So I'm trying to apply a boatload of updates and upgrades via Ubuntu's built-in update system... But it tells me the updates/upgrades can't be completed because it requires the installation of "untrusted" packages.

For the most part, my software has been installed via the Ubuntu Software Center... But there are a few odds and ends that I have installed separately...

The thing is, even the "Ubuntu base" updates (which as I understand it, as from Ubuntu themselves) are considered "untrusted" when I try to install them individually!

I've had a play around in the relevant settings, but no matter what I click, Ubuntu simply does not want to apply these updates/upgrades!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've installed packages from ppa it may happen. To unblock the updates, I'd suggest to open the Software Sources and deselect a few of them (temporarily):

1. Open the Ubuntu Software Center,
2. then Edit-> Software Sources...
3. Finally open the "Other Software" tab

After deselecting a ppa, try again to open the Software Updater to request an update. It should quickly give you the untrusted source.

As pointed by karel, you can also update your system using `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` on the command line. It will prompt you if you want to install such packages.

Comment: Yeah, I used the Terminal command and it fixed everything. I was in a rush (I was trying to do something else at the same time) and didn't bother to read what package/s were causing the issue... Oops!