# Can't update software - untrusted packages/indel files failed to download

Tags: package-management, updates, update-manager

When I try to update via Software Updater, I am shown this error:
[image: Requires installation of untrusted packages]

Of course, one would normally fix this with (as I have previously asked about [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431246/cant-update-because-of-untrusted-packages)) :

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

However, this simply produces its own errors:

```
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
ones used instead.
```

I thought this might be related to some sort of connectivity issue, but I get the same error irrespective of whether my VPN is running or not... Not to mention the fact that everything else has no connectivity issues.

Any help would be appreciated...

By the way, here is the full Terminal spiel:

```
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise InRelease                    
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                         
Ign http://download.opensuse.org  InRelease                           
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring InRelease                   
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                             
Get:1 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease [3,300 B]        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                         
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                    
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease              
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Sources                
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                       
Ign http://download.opensuse.org  InRelease                           
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg                 
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free amd64
Packages/DiffIndex      Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg            
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                           
Hit http://download.opensuse.org  Release.gpg                         
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free i386
Packages/DiffIndex       Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring
Release                               Hit http://dl.google.com stable
Release                                         Ign
http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                             
Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release                
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam amd64 Packages         
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                      
Hit http://download.opensuse.org  Release.gpg                         
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring/main amd64 Packages         
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                         
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources           
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages               
Hit http://download.opensuse.org  Release                             
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring/restricted amd64 Packages   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                         
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                    
Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease             
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam i386 Packages          
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                
Hit http://download.opensuse.org  Release                             
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring/universe amd64 Packages     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                         
Hit http://download.opensuse.org  Packages                            
Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease           
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse amd64 Packages   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources       
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages          
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources     
Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                   
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring/restricted i386 Packages    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages    
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring/universe i386 Packages      
Hit http://download.opensuse.org  Packages                            
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                         
Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg           
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64
Packages        Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse
i386 Packages              Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty
InRelease                                   Hit
http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages    
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en_AU      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                       
Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg         
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64
Packages        Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg       
Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                       
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en_AU
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages     
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_AU                
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_AU            
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                       
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386
Packages         Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates
Release                         Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com
trusty/main Translation-en                         Hit
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en_AU    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages 
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                       
Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release             
Hit http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free amd64 Packages      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386
Packages         Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg      
Hit http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free i386 Packages       
Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources/DiffIndex        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en    
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg [316 B]             
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en_AU   
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse
Translation-en        Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg 
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en      
Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources/DiffIndex  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted
Translation-en        Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg 
Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources/DiffIndex    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en_AU  
Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                           
Ign http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Translation-en_AU      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                           
Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex 
Ign http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Translation-en         
Ign http://download.opensuse.org  Translation-en_AU                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                           
Ign http://download.opensuse.org  Translation-en                      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                           
Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64
Packages/DiffIndex     Ign http://download.opensuse.org 
Translation-en_AU                             Hit
http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                               
Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64
Packages/DiffIndex       Ign http://download.opensuse.org 
Translation-en                                Hit
http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                           
Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64
Packages/DiffIndex     Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                           
Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                           
Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386
Packages/DiffIndex      Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages               
Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386
Packages/DiffIndex        Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main
i386 Packages                          Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net
trusty/main Translation-en                         Ign
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages               
Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources/DiffIndex
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                
Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted
Sources/DiffIndex    Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main
Translation-en                         Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net
trusty/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex               Ign
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex      
Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse
Sources/DiffIndex    Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com
trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex   Hit
http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                   
Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64
Packages/DiffIndex Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386
Packages                          Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net
trusty/main Translation-en                         Ign
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64
Packages/DiffIndex Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64
Packages                         Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com
trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex Hit
http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en               
Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386
Packages/DiffIndex    Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64
Packages                         Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net
trusty/main i386 Packages                          Ign
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386
Packages/DiffIndex Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main
Translation-en                         Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net
trusty/main amd64 Packages                         Ign
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386
Packages/DiffIndex Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386
Packages                          Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com
trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex Ign
http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_AU                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en               
Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main
Sources/DiffIndex        Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com
trusty-backports/restricted Sources/DiffIndex  Ign
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe
Sources/DiffIndex    Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com
trusty-backports/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex  Ign
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64
Packages/DiffIndex Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com
trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex Ign
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64
Packages/DiffIndex Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com
trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex Ign
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386
Packages/DiffIndex Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com
trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex Ign
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386
Packages/DiffIndex Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com
trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex Ign
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_AU Ign
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en Ign
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_AU Ign
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en Ign
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_AU Ign
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en Ign
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_AU Ign
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en Ign
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en_AU Ign
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en Ign
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse
Translation-en_AU Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com
trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en Ign
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted
Translation-en_AU Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com
trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en Ign
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en_AU
Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe
Translation-en Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main
Translation-en_AU Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com
trusty-backports/main Translation-en Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com
trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en_AU Ign
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse
Translation-en Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com
trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en_AU Ign
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted
Translation-en Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com
trusty-backports/universe Translation-en_AU Ign
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en
Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources   404  Not Found
[IP: 202.158.214.106 80] Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com
trusty/restricted Sources   404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources   404  Not
Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80] Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com
trusty/multiverse Sources   404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages   404  Not
Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80] Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com
trusty/restricted amd64 Packages   404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106
80] Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages  
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80] Err
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages   404 
Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80] Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com
trusty/main i386 Packages   404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages   404
Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80] Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com
trusty/universe i386 Packages   404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106
80] Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages  
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80] Err
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources   404  Not
Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80] Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com
trusty-updates/restricted Sources   404  Not Found [IP:
202.158.214.106 80] Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources   404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106
80] Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80] Err
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages   404 
Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80] Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com
trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages   404  Not Found [IP:
202.158.214.106 80] Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages   404  Not Found [IP:
202.158.214.106 80] Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages   404  Not Found [IP:
202.158.214.106 80] Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages   404  Not Found [IP:
202.158.214.106 80] Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages   404  Not Found [IP:
202.158.214.106 80] Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages   404  Not Found [IP:
202.158.214.106 80] Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages   404  Not Found [IP:
202.158.214.106 80] Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources   404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106
80] Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted
Sources   404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80] Err
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources   404 
Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80] Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com
trusty-backports/multiverse Sources   404  Not Found [IP:
202.158.214.106 80] Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages   404  Not Found [IP:
202.158.214.106 80] Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages   404  Not Found [IP:
202.158.214.106 80] Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages   404  Not Found [IP:
202.158.214.106 80] Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages   404  Not Found [IP:
202.158.214.106 80] Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages   404  Not Found [IP:
202.158.214.106 80] Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages   404  Not Found [IP:
202.158.214.106 80] Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages   404  Not Found [IP:
202.158.214.106 80] Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages   404  Not Found [IP:
202.158.214.106 80] Fetched 3,616 B in 4min 28s (13 B/s) W: GPG error: http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease: The following
signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not
available: NO_PUBKEY 13B00F1FD2C19886 W: GPG error:
http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures
couldn't be verified because the public key is not available:
NO_PUBKEY 4DF9B28CA252A784 W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources 
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/source/Sources
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/source/Sources
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/source/Sources
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/binary-amd64/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/binary-i386/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/source/Sources
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/source/Sources
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/source/Sources
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/source/Sources
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/main/source/Sources
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/restricted/source/Sources
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/universe/source/Sources
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/multiverse/source/Sources
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/universe/binary-amd64/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
ones used instead.
```

Comment: Why are you mixing multiple Ubuntu releases? I saw entries for Raring and Trusty.

Comment: I don't even know why they are there... This particular computer was a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ("Trusty Tahr") setup from the start; it's never run anything else.

Should I remove those entries?

Comment: Absolutely. You should change them to say Trusty, but if that gives errors you should remove it altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://au.archive.ubuntu.com is down and for some wacky reason runs on a redhat server :)

Switch to a different mirror for now or try again later.

- Search for "software" in your dash and click on **Software & Updates**.
- Click on the drop-down menu for **Download From** and select **other**.
- Then, click on **select best server** to automatically select the best server or you can just click on **main server** instead but it probably won't be as fast.

You can contact the maintainer of the mirror here http://aarnet.edu.au/contact-us/enquiry-and-feedback-form to let them know the repo is down.

---

UPDATE:

http://au.archive.ubuntu.com  appears to be back up again and Software Updater should run ok.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
enter the terminal
and type this: sudo bash
gedit /etc/atp/sources.list
```

and then do this

```
put ## in front of src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com etc..
```

and you might could update again, and it might work fine this way.